# Kafka exclusive consumer retry behaviour

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I need some understanding on the Kafka exclusive consumer retry behaviour for fixed back off.

Exclusive consumer is reading data from a topic having 6 partitions. All 6 partitions have data.
FixedBackOff(30000, 100) is applied to consumer for failure retry case.

1. Consumer read data from partition-0 and processing fails, retry with 30 secs interval starts happening. Will the consumer keeps on retrying this record from partition-0 or will the consumer can read data from partition-1 and process and holds data from partition-0 during next poll() ?
2. If it can hold data, then how does kafka ensures fixed backoff of 30 secs for every record in flight?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the records will be returned in the same order, sometimes they will, sometimes they won't.

You either need to increase the `concurrency` so you have a consumer for each partition, or set the new property available in 2.9.6...

```java
/**
 * When true (default), the error handler will perform seeks on the failed and/or
 * remaining records to they will be redelivered on the next poll. When false, the
 * container will present the failed and/or remaining records to the listener by
 * pausing the consumer for the next poll and using the existing records from the
 * previous poll. When false; has the side-effect of setting
 * {@link #setResetStateOnExceptionChange(boolean)} to true.
 * @param seekAfterError false to not perform seeks.
 * @since 2.9
 */
public void setSeekAfterError(boolean seekAfterError) {
```